# Do I need to fly along this spiked tunnel to get the secret exit?

Tags: nimbus

So, while solving level 4-1, I passed the following sign.

[image]

Having flown below the secret I can see red "exit" blocks up there, which I know from previous levels will unlock a second path in the main world.

I can't get up that passage, so either I've missed something, or the dev's are lying to me.

Which is it, and how do I get the secret exit that's mentioned here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do need to go through that tunnel to get the secret.

The key to getting it, is starting the level, and then tapping <kbd>UPARROW</kbd> once, and then leaving the game to do it's own thing.

Comment: Ha, those sneaky gits... never would have thought of leaving the controls. Thanks! And damn, I bet that took a while to fine-tune the level so it worked :)

Comment: I'm so glad I figured this out myself. :)